# What is causing this #pragma warning restore 1998

Tags: asp.net-core, pragma, asp.net-apicontroller

learning asp.net core for 1st time.

I have a view.

inside that view I am loading a html.Partial view.

In that partial view I am calling my api controller.

I get a #pragma warning restore 1998 error.

This is my view (stripped down to relevancy I hope!)...

```
@model MyDomain.Services.Models.Account

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="divLogForm" class="modal-dialog" style="display:none;position:absolute; ">
    <div style="background-color: #fefefe;margin: auto;padding: 20px;border: 1px solid #888;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="hdrTitle">LogIn</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @await Html.PartialAsync( "~/Views/Segments/_Registration.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

This is my _Registration view....

```
@model MyDomain.Services.Models.Account

<div class="row" style="display:none" id="divRegistration">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registration.EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registration.Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registration.ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
            </div>
            <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Invalid registration</div>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
        <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are my Models:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Registration Registration { get; set; }
}


public class Registration
{
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Email address not found")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?", ErrorMessage = "Password should at length of 5 and include upper/lower letter and contain a number")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,32}$)?", ErrorMessage = "Password should at length of 5 and include upper/lower letter and contain a number")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match, Type again!")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Register([Bind("EmailAddress,Password")] Registration registration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do some thing
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the Registration button I get this:

[image]

I set a breakpoint in this controller method but it is never hit.

I was going to post the results from the 'Show Compliation Source'  but it is quite verbise but on inspection I do not see anything obvious there that would help me.

So.. I am sure I am doing a howler here and I wish I had not been on a contract for the last 2 years doing Windows  Desktop Forms (had to recession, needed cash :) ) as I have seem to have forgotten everything about web...

Also, how can I go about (for future reference) in diagnosing this pragma errors?

There is nothing in the windows logs. There are no warnings in my IDE for me to investigate.

All advice is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: One thing I noticed is you're not passing a model to your partial. Seeing as the model of your view and partial are the same, do this. `@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Segments/_Registration.cshtml", Model); }`. Also you haven't listed your Get action for Account/Register.

Comment: @ma sorry for the delay. i shall give that a go in a sec :)thanks

Comment: @CodeCaster please be more helpful instead of... cheers

Comment: Instead of what? We can't troubleshoot an issue for you if you don't provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CodeCaster not sure what the issue is here. I posted my code. I get an error. I cannot work out what the error was as I have no clues to go by.  So as i said 2 parts to my question how (not a what) do people go about solving/diagnosing a pragma error and also is there some thing obvious wrong with my code. As it is the comment by #mardox solved the 2nd part of my question and I would still be interested in an answer to the 1st part of my question.